# Libvirt on Xenserver 6.5

Tags: citrix, xen, centos5, libvirt

I am trying to install Libvirt with Xen driver on the Opensource Xenserver 6.5. I found that the XenAPI driver lacks some of the APIs like "virConnectNumOfStoragePools" which I need for my work. Hence, I will need to use the libxl or xenlight driver to make this happen. I referred the API Support for libvirt for this decision (https://libvirt.org/hvsupport.html).

I am Unable to get the Xen driver configured with the Libvirt.

Here are the details :-

I failed to find a useful repository that I could use to install the libvirt with Xen driver. Hence, I chose to compile the Libvirt by myself on the Xenserver.

I downloaded Xenserver SDK and installed the `libxenserver` library from the following link :-

http://xenserver.org/partners/developing-products-for-xenserver.html

Post that, I downloaded `libvirt-1.2.21` and ran `autogen.sh` which led to the following `configure` command :-

`running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --with-xenapi=/usr/local/lib --with-curl=yes --with-xen=/usr/local/lib --with-gnutls=yes --with-libxl=/usr/local/lib --no-create --no-recursion`

The configure script dumped the following data among others :-

```
configure:       Xen: no 
configure:      QEMU: yes
configure:       UML: yes
configure:    OpenVZ: yes
configure:    VMware: yes
configure:      VBox: yes
configure:    XenAPI: yes
configure:  xenlight: no
configure:       LXC: no
configure:      PHYP: no
configure:       ESX: yes
configure:   Hyper-V: no
configure:        vz: no
configure:     Bhyve: no
configure:      Test: yes
configure:    Remote: yes
configure:   Network: yes
configure:  Libvirtd: yes
configure: Interface: no
configure:   macvtap: no
configure:  virtport: no
```

It looks like the `configure` script did not find the relevant Xen libraries and include files.

The `virsh` reports the following after installation :-

```
Virsh command line tool of libvirt 1.2.21
See web site at http://libvirt.org/


Compiled with support for:
 Hypervisors: QEMU/KVM UML OpenVZ VMWare VirtualBox ESX XenAPI Test
 Networking: Remote Network Bridging Nwfilter
 Storage: Dir Filesystem SCSI Multipath iSCSI LVM
 Miscellaneous: Daemon SELinux Secrets Debug Modular
```

Useful Info :-

The Kernel for the Xenserver is : 3.10.0+2

Architecture: x86_64

LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch

Any pointers on if I am missing any configuration or relevant library would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Libvirt does work with the XenAPI, as I am able to use the Virsh to administer the Xenserver. However, as mentioned in the question, XenAPI lacks some API support which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

While libvirt does technically have a XenAPI driver, it is effectively unmaintained at this point. The original contributor who wrote it, left Citrix many years ago and no one has stepped forward to take over development of it. So unfortunately, there's not going to be any good answer to solving your problem of missing features in the XenAPI impl of libvirt.